# Dynamic form building - cleanest way to substitute tags with form elements?

Tags: theming, forms

I have a string with tags, and form elements with elements corresponding to that tags:

```
$line = "This module contains [quantity] items of type [type]."
$elements = array(
  'quantity' => array (
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    //other settings
  ),
  'type' =>  array (
    '#type' => 'select',
    //other settings
  ),
}
```

Now, I have:

[image: This module contains (tag) items of type (tag). Two form fields after this string.]

I want to generate:

[image: This module contains (quantity textbox) items of type (type dropdown) .]

What's the most standard Drupal way to do this? Elements and string will be taken from database. I assume it should happen in hook_theme, but how to pass all values to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand what you need to do is:

1. Remove `div` around form elements and `label` next to from elements.
2. Put form elements in a right place.

I don't think there is a "one true way" of doing those. But here is how I would do it.

To do first use a #theme_wrappers setting of a form element to override default one.

```
$form['quantity'] = array (
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#theme_wrappers' => array('custom_form_element')
  //other settings
);
$form['type'] = array (
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#theme_wrappers' => array('custom_form_element')
);
```

You the will need to implement `hook_theme` in your module to define `theme_custom_form_element` themer function.

```
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'custom_form_element' => array(
      'render element' => 'element'
    )       
  );
}
```

Then you will need to implement the actual themer function. Look at `function theme_form_element($variables)` in `includes/form.inc` for reference. Yours should be much simplier, something like:

```
function theme_custom_form_element($vars) {
  return $variables['element']['#children'];
}
```

That should output only `<input />` html tags without surrounding divs - perfect for inline layout.

To put form elements into right places in the string I would suggest having another form element to store a string like that:

```
$string = db_query ... something ...

$form['tagged_str'] = array(
  '#type' => 'value',
  '#value' => $string
);
```

Also in form constructor provide a themer for the whole form like that:

```
$form['#theme'] = 'inline_elements_form';
```

(Name `inline_elements_form` is a result of my poor ability to come up with good names, you can name it anyway you want.)

You will then have to make changes to `hook_theme` implementation to register a new themer

```
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'custom_form_element' => array(
      'render element' => 'element'
    ),
    'inline_elements_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form'
    )      
  );
}
```

Now when you will be implementing theme function for the form you will have all from elements available to you.

```
function theme_inline_elements_form($vars) {
  $string = $vars['form']['tagged_str']['#value'];
  $quantity = drupal_render($vars['form']['quantity']);
  $type = drupal_render($vars['form']['type']);

  $output = str_replace(
    array('[quantity]', '[type]'),
    array($quantity, $type),
    $string);

  return $output . drupal_render_children($vars['form']); 
  //NOTE: calling drupal_render_children is important to have the form working correctly
}
```

This is not quite as extensible as you might want. But I was aiming to give an idea of how you can customize forms an form elements.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I needed.

Comment: I didn't use exactly this code, but this approach certainly worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If the tags are not dynamic you can have an array of possible form elements and then just foreach over them with matches from a regex. Then just have your mymodule_form call a builder function that would look something like:

```
<?php
function my_dynamic_forms_dynamic_form($form, &$form_state, $id) {
  $string = my_dynamic_forms_db_call_for_strings($id);

  $elements = my_dyanmic_forms_get_array_elements();

  $form = array();

  $reg = '/\[(.*?)\]/is';

  if($c = preg_match_all($reg, $string, $matches))
  {
    foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
      $form[$match] = $elements[$match];
    }
  }

  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit Form',
  );

  return $form;
}


function my_dyanmic_forms_get_array_elements() {
  $elements = array(
  'quantity' => array (
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    //other settings
  ),
  'type' =>  array (
    '#type' => 'select',
    //other settings
  ));

  return $elements;
}

function my_dynamic_forms_db_call_for_strings($id) {
  $sql = 'SELECT string s from my_dynamic_form_strings_table s WHERE id = :id';

  $result = db_query($sql, array(':id', $id));

  return $result->fetchField();
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks like a decent way to detect tags. How to make it a Form API form and perform actual substitution?

Comment: I do have it already. My problem is between "Now, I have" and "I want to generate" in my question.

Comment: It's performing the substition, the $form array at the end is actually kicking out elements from the elements array.  You just put this code at the top of your form builder function and farm out your elements to a builder function and call your string.  Something like `$string = my_dynamic_forms_db_call_for_strings();` and call to `$elements = my_dyanmic_forms_get_array_elements();`

Comment: I've clarified the code to match my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use either a custom form function or [hook_forms()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_forms/7) to create a custom form builder function that outputs a FAPI array.

Then in your function you simply build each form item, it looks something like this. I do some extra stuff like include a confirmation page for my form submission -- I'm yanking this out of existing code and trimming out some private info.

I'm not showing you the code to tear apart the string to get the form elements -- this is how to build a `$form` from database data like what you have and get a valid usable `$form` in Drupal.

```
/**
 * implementation of hook_forms().
 *
 * Normally drupal looks for a function of the form FORM_ID_form to build a
 * $form. In this case we are essentially using the custom form generator to build
 * each form more-or-less the same, but we still want each form to have a
 * unique $form_id. So, we use hook_forms() to build a kind of form factory
 * where each $form_id ultimately maps to 1 builder function.
 *
 * Drupal takes care of caching forms its previously built. Drupal also uses
 * this building knowledge to test that a submitted form "validates" as
 * un-tampered upon form submittal (this is seperate from custom form
 * validation).
 *
 * We can call this like:
 *   $form = drupal_get_form('mymodule_custom_form_2345');
 *   or
 *   $form = drupal_get_form('mymodule_custom_form_2346778');
 *
 * Each form is unique, built by our rules below.
 */
function mymodule_forms($form_id, $args) {
  $forms = array();
  if (strpos($form_id,'mymodule_custom_') === 0) {
    $forms[$form_id] = array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_custom_form',
      // From API.docs the 'callback arguments' always contain $args. They are
      // always passed along to the form_builder().
    );

    return $forms;
  }
}



/**
 * This is our custom generic form builder function used to build all unique
 * $form_id Survey forms. By default drupal looks for a similarly named
 * function with _submit appended to it to handle form submission.
 */
function mymodule_custom_form($form_id, &$form_state, $args) {

  $args = func_get_args();
  // Eg, /some/path/23432432
  // because on this site all these customs forms use this type of path.
  $survey_id = $args[2];

  if (!isset($form_state['storage']['confirm'])) {
    $form = array();
    $form = _mymodule_build_fapi_array($survey_id);
    //
    // Add extra form elements here, such as to our custom submit and validation
    // handlers.

    // http://drupal.org/node/751826
    return $form;
  }
  else
  {

    #
    # Show a confirmation form.
    #

    $title = _mymodule_get_form_title($survey_id);
    return confirm_form(
        array(),
        'Are you sure you want to submit this form?',
        'site/my-surveys',
        "You are about to submit your answers for $title.<br><br>You will no longer be able to access or edit the survey you are about to submit as survey responses are anonymous. Are you sure you want to submit this survey?",
        'Yes, Submit the survey',
        'No, discard my answers and Start Over');
  }
}


  function _mymodule_build_fapi_array($survey_id) {
    $form = array();

    $form_items = db_query('SELECT question FROM {your_questions_table} WHERE id = :id', array(':id', $survey_id)->fetchAll());

    // These functions just generate individual FAPI elements.
    foreach ($form_items as $Q) {
      switch (strtolower($Q->question_type)) {
        case 'scalar':
          $form[$Q->item_number]= _generate_scalar_question($Q);
          break;
        case 'text':
          $form[$Q->item_number]= _generate_text_question($Q);
          break;
        case 'header':
          $form[$Q->item_number]= _generate_header_question($Q);
      }
    }
    return $form;
  }
```

Comment: I must admit I don't get how this apply to my case. I mean, I generate for all right, I switch via fields type, my form generation UI works. Only problem is: Now I have string with tags, and I want to put the very form elements in place of these tags. The very output is a problem, that's why there is **I assume it should happen in hook_theme** in my question from the very beginning.

Comment: well. if its just the output you're trying to theme like your example -- good luck. the default theme elements dont really allow inlining like you've included on your page. In part that is because a Form with tab-indexes doesnt really lend itself to display like a sentence with inline form inputs. You have other issues like small screens and mobile devices that wont render the example sentence you provide the same on all devices. Forms look ugly because their UI is accessible. try CSS `display: inline;` on your form inputs.

Comment: "final" image was there from the very beginning, that's what I want and wanted. I never had serious problems with tab order for inlined elements in pure html+php. Well, no more than with "regular" ones. About small screens - not an issue for me. And even if it was, inlined form takes less space, not more, as that way I can omit unneeded explanation - user sees directly what part of data he edits, so he does not need to read label to know. I'll deal with it when / if it'll start to make problems to my case. For now this whole form is excluded in mobile anyway.